# Python: yfinance unable to handle exceptions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datareader, yfinance

Forgive me if I am unclear as I am new to posting on here.

Trying to pull data and tickers from yahoo finance using the following code. When pulling from yfinance, I want to keep track of each of the tickers that fail to download (whether it be due to the stock being delisted or other) by adding to an empty list called "stocks_not_downloaded". To do so I am using a try / except block so that if a stock fails to download it appends to the stocks_not_downloaded list.

When running the code, the stocks download and when an exception is reached it shows for example "1 Failed download:
['Ticker']: Exception('%ticker%: No timezone found, symbol may be delisted')"

BUT

A) it fails to print("Could not Get Data for:", ticker) which I have set it to do and...
B) when running the stocks_not_downloaded_list it returns "[]" - an empty list

It seems to be failing to recognize the error as a normal exception despite outputting the above message. I read that there may be something weird with yfinance, but I cannot figure it out.

I will post the code and the output. Thanks in advance.

I am using this data set (https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ANM0er8uwPV%2DmRg&id=3B0309A579EBD636%2113144&cid=3B0309A579EBD636) - not sure if its sketch to link a onedrive but let me know if you want it in another format.

**Code**

```
#Imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
%matplotlib inline

import datetime as dt
import mplfinance as mpf

import time

import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override()
stocks_not_downloaded = []
missing_stocks = []


#Saves Stock Data to CSV
def save_to_csv_from_yahoo(folder, ticker, syear, smonth, sday, eyear, emonth, eday):
        start = dt.datetime(syear, smonth, sday)
        end = dt.datetime(eyear, emonth, eday)
         
        try:
            print("Get Data for :", ticker)
            df = web.DataReader(ticker, start, end)["Adj Close"]
            time.sleep(10)
            df.to_csv(folder + ticker + ".csv")
        
        except Exception as ex:
            stocks_not_downloaded.append(ticker)
            print("Could not Get Data for:", ticker)

#Returns a Named Column Data from CSV
def get_column_from_csv(file, col_name):
        try:
            df = pd.read_csv(file)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("File Does Not Exist")
        else:
            return df[col_name]
    
#Defines tickers and folder
tickers = get_column_from_csv("C:/Users/15189/Documents/Python_For_Finance/Wilshire-5000-Stocks.csv","Ticker")
    
folder = "/Users/15189/Documents/Python_For_Finance/Stock_List/"
    
for x in range(20):
        save_to_csv_from_yahoo(folder, tickers[x], 2017, 1, 1, 2021, 8, 19)
    
print("Finished")
stocks_not_downloaded
```

As you can see I am using:

```
        try:
            print("Get Data for :", ticker)
            df = web.DataReader(ticker, start, end)["Adj Close"]
            time.sleep(10)
            df.to_csv(folder + ticker + ".csv")
        
        except Exception as ex:
            stocks_not_downloaded.append(ticker)
            print("Could not Get Data for:", ticker)
```

But when running:

```
for x in range(20):
        save_to_csv_from_yahoo(folder, tickers[x], 2017, 1, 1, 2021, 8, 19)
    
print("Finished")
stocks_not_downloaded
```

I get the following output with a "[]" at the end - an empty list for stocks not downloaded along with no "Could not get data for:" message. I really appreciate any insight

**Output:**

```
Get Data for : A
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed
Get Data for : AA
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed
Get Data for : AAL
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed
Get Data for : AAME
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed
Get Data for : AAN
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed
Get Data for : AAOI
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed
Get Data for : AAON
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed
Get Data for : AAP
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed
Get Data for : AAPL
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed
Get Data for : AAT
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed
Get Data for : AAWW
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed

1 Failed download:
['AAWW']: Exception('%ticker%: No timezone found, symbol may be delisted')

Get Data for : AAXN
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed

1 Failed download:
['AAXN']: Exception('%ticker%: No timezone found, symbol may be delisted')

Get Data for : ABBV
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed
Get Data for : ABC
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed
Get Data for : ABCB
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed
Get Data for : ABEO
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed
Get Data for : ABG
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed
Get Data for : ABIO
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed
Get Data for : ABM
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed
Get Data for : ABMD
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed
Finished
[]
```

Comment: Pleas read the Minimal aspect of [mre]

Comment: maybe `DataReade` displays error but it not raise error - so `except Exception as ex:` can't catch it and it can't append `ticker` to `stocks_not_downloaded`. Your code does't shows `print("Could not Get Data for:", ticker)` - so it looks like it does't run this part of code.. Maybe you have to check if `df` is not empty and then append `ticker` to `stocks_not_downloaded`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly why the error isn't being picked up. I tried it locally and having the same problem. Seems to be how pandas_datareader handles raised errors.

One option you could do is check if the Adj Close is empty:

```
try:
    print("Get Data for :", ticker)
    df = web.DataReader(ticker, start, end)["Adj Close"]
    if df.empty:
        print("No Data for :", ticker)
        stocks_not_downloaded.append(ticker)
        pass
    time.sleep(10)
    df.to_csv(folder + ticker + ".csv")
```

Looks like pandas-datareader has a yahoo reader built in also. Might be worth a shot: https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readers/yahoo.html

Comment: This worked I appreciate it. I will also look into the reader. I was using a youtube video to figure some of this out and had to make a few changes as the video was old. may be something to do with updates to data.reader() or trouble with the yfinance override().

Answer (score 0):

yfinance appears to be off-line, message states that engineers are working on the issue, but I can't find any updates or timeline on how much longer it will be offline.